# how can i get index array php from condition below

Tags: php, arrays

```
$lang_result = array();

function f_language($lang)
{
    if (is_array($lang) === true)
    {
        foreach ($lang as $key => $value)
        {
            $temp[] = "'$value'";
        }
        $lang = implode(',',$temp);
    }    
    $qryLang = mssql_query ("
                SELECT LANG_CODE,LANG_TEXT
                FROM TLANGUAGE
                WHERE LANG_ID = 'EN' --coocie.lang_id
                AND LANG_CODE in ($lang) 
            ");

    global $lang_result;
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($qryLang))
    {
        array_push($lang_result,array("$row[LANG_CODE]" => "$row[LANG_TEXT]"));
    }
}
$lang_code = array();
array_push($lang_code,'ofc','sch');
#array_push($lang_code,'sch');
f_language($lang_code);
echo "<hr/>";
var_dump($lang_result);
```

**Output:**

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["ofc"]=> string(6) "office" }
       [1]=> array(1) { ["sch"]=> string(6) "school" } 
     }
```

I tried with `(array_search('office',$lang_result));` then i didn't get the index value. 
somebody kindly please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or replace

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($qryLang))
{
  array_push($lang_result,array("$row[LANG_CODE]" => "$row[LANG_TEXT]"));
}
```

With

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($qryLang))
{
  $lang_result[$row[LANG_CODE]] = $row[LANG_TEXT];
}
```

This will prevent the array becoming multi dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `$lang_result` is an array that has array elements. I'd suggest you do `foreach` on `$lang_result` (or even better `for`, so you get a counter right away) and *then* use `array_search` to find if there is a match, and then mark that element using a counter.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because $lang_result is a multidimensional array. You need to seach in each of the subarrays. Try this function:

```
<?php
$lang_result = array(
    array("ofc" => "office"),
    array("sch" => "school")
    );

function search_text(&$array, $text)
// {{{
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $result = array_search($text, $value);
        if ($result != FALSE)
        {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
// }}}

print search_text($lang_result, "office")."\n";
var_dump(search_text($lang_result, "crap"));
?>
```

This code prints:

```
ofc 
bool(false)
```

I think, that's what you need.